# Divide number with aligned print

Tags: c, numbers, codeblocks

I'm working on a C program that divides a number in prime factors.
It prints like this:

[image: how it looks compiled]

Can i align that that line in the middle somehow?

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows what you have tried. Show the input, the expected output, and the actual output **as text** *in the question*.

Comment: That that line? Which line? In the middle of what?

Comment: With `printf("%10d|%d", val1, val2)` you can. Please read the documentation on `printf`, it's explained there how to do it.

Comment: @Pablo `printf("%10d|%d", val1, val2)` will not align with large negative values.  Better to avoid magic numbers.

Comment: Catalin Woods A good question would post the type of `x` and the range of values it might have.

Answer (score 3):

You can align the numbers using a padding format attribute in [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf); thereby, you will also align the "line in the middle":

```
int  main() {
    const char* format = "%5d | %d\n";
    printf(format, 625,5);
    printf(format, 125,5);
    printf(format, 25,5);
    printf(format, 5,5);
}
```

Output:

```
  625 | 5
  125 | 5
   25 | 5
    5 | 5
```

Comment: Ah, you got what I failed to see in the poorly asked question, but I suggest `format = "%5d | %d\n"`